# Loading FBX model into DirectX application

Tags: math, graphics, 3d, direct3d, fbx

I am trying to render a 3d model from FBX file in my directx application,
so I have loaded it using fbx sdk, but I found a big problem, probably caused by different coordinate system: DirectX use left handed, Fbx - right handed,
so finally I got it rendered, but with two issues:

- all parts of the model look mirrored by Z axis (or by X - its not clear)
- position of the parts is incorrect after applying transformation matrix provided by FBX for 
  each part;

So how what I can do with Vertex data and/or transformation matrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to save the model and transformation data in your application differently than they are stored in the file. In general, it sounds like what you need to do is:

- Load the FBX
- Apply the transformations to each part according to the FBX
- Apply the transformation to invert the Z-axis on all of the vertices
- Render/use the resulting model.

Applying the FBX transformations in the wrong coordinate systems will yield incorrect results.

Comment: Thank you for answer, all parts look ok now, but their position still incorrect...

Comment: The rotation looks ok, seems something wrong with translation and/or scaling

Comment: Just found solution. I did not use GeometryTransform matrix, wich is from "known issues" of Fbx sdk, described in readme.txt, so FBX documentation is very bad, since I had to spent time on it